# SQLite django download not showing file

Tags: html, django, database, sqlite

I am having trouble downloading a file from my sqlite database using django.
I have created a db model. i then went into my django admin and uploaded the file.
Then in the `index.html` I set a download link. However when i press the download link my page just seems to refresh and nothing downloads. The app i have created is called `chartsapp`. maybe it is something to do with my line of code `{{ chartsapp.the_file.url }}`. i have played around with it trying `the_file.url` but that didn't seem to do anything either. any advice?

MODELS.PY

```
from django.db import models

class Datahere(models.Model):
    text = models.FileField(upload_to='Uploaded')
```

ADMIN.PY

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Datahere

admin.site.register(Datahere)
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<a href="{{ chartsapp.the_file.url }}">Download the file</a>
```

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),

]
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Datahere

def index(request):
    model = Datahere
    return render(request, "index.html", {})
```

Comment: How is `{{ chartsapp.the_file.url }}` supposed to work? What is your site's logic? Could you share your view

Comment: I thought this opens the absolute path to the file in the database? hence opens the file? I have just started so dont really know what im doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am still a beginner at django , but if you want your url working , you must add the url to urls.py file , then editing in views.py .
I hope this will help .

Comment: i have added my `urls.py` and `views.py` in the question

Comment: Oh I missed that sorry about that

Comment: My last answer for my few information about django , sorry about that again , I am still learning , in the terminal do , python manage.py makemigration , after that python manage.py migrate .

Comment: Go to the folder that contain manage.py file , then try again the two commands from the previous answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't download a file from your sqlite database. Instead your model saves any file/image/etc. to `MEDIA_ROOT/Uploaded` with `MEDIA_ROOT` defined in your **settings.py** like so:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

The database itself doesn't store media files (and static) at all. It just stores the location of the file as path relative to `MEDIA_ROOT`.

So to render the link to the file in your template as desired, you can go ahead like so:

```
{% load static %}
<body data-media-url="{% get_media_prefix as MEDIA_PREFIX %}">

<img src="{{ MEDIA_PREFIX }}images/your_image.png">

or 

<a href="{{ MEDIA_PREFIX }}pdfs/your_file.pdf">Download the file</a>
```

As long as in development, you will also need to add the urls to your`urls.py` like so:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] 

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also you should consider to rename your Model field into something different than `text` when storing files, for me it is quiet misleading and uncertain.

For further reference about `FileField` and `ImageField` check out the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/).

Comment: I a getting an error because the "Monthly Sale.pdf" that i uploaded is not stored in static folder.

Comment: @pete800 try the above solution. It works on my end.